# Remove an Element in Array on Leet code. I am getting an error of getting incompatible types and I dont know whats wrong

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Here is the question:

> Given an integer array `nums` and an integer `val`, remove all
> occurrences of `val` in `nums` in place. The relative order of the
> elements may be changed.
>
> Since it is impossible to change the length of the array in some
> languages, you must instead have the result be placed in the first
> part of the array `nums`.
>
> More formally, if there are k elements after removing the duplicates,
> then the first `k` elements of `nums` should hold the final result. It
> does not matter what you leave beyond the first k elements.
>
> Return `k` after placing the final result in the first `k` slots of
> `nums`.
>
> Do not allocate extra space for another array. You must do this by
> modifying the input array in-place with **O(1)** extra memory.

I've tried to remove the given target `val` by shifting the value to the end of the array index by iteration of `nums.length-1` every time the `val` is found in the given array. I just want to know what's wrong with my approach.

Below is the code I've tried:

```
class Solution {
    public int removeElement(int[] nums, int val) {

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

            if (val == nums[i]) {

                for (int j = i; j < nums.length - 1; j++) {
                    nums[j + 1] = nums[j];
                }
                break;
            }

        }
        return nums;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm correctly would be the following. The error was returning the array, but that was changed in-situ. You should have returned the new reduced length.

```
public int removeElement(int[] nums, int val) {
    int k = nums.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        if (val == nums[i]) {
            --k;
            //for (int j = i; i < k; j++) {
            //    nums[j] = nums[j + 1];
            //}
            System.arraycopy(nums, i+1, nums, i, k-i);
            --i; // Check the new nums[i] too
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

The for-j loop can be replaced with System.arraycopy (which handles overlapping of the same array too).

Or:

```
public int removeElement(int[] nums, int val) {
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (val != nums[i]) {
            nums[k] = nums[i];
            ++k;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code in leetcode. Hope will help you

```
    class Solution {
   public int removeElement(int[] nums, int val) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
            if(nums[i]!=val){
                list.add(nums[i]);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            nums[i]= list.get(i);
        }
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer does not take care of one of the requirements in the question: "Do not allocate extra space for another array.".

Comment: This algorithm is working in leetcode without any exception.